# Opening a custom URL in new tab from a middle click in Firefox

Tags: javascript, events, firefox, mouseclick-event

So, currently I have a script which intercepts any mouse clicks on  tags, modifies the outgoing link, and sends users on their way:

```
$("a[href*='" + someDomain + "']").bind('click keypress', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var link = this.href;
    var newLink = link + params;
    var button = event.button;
    if(button && button == 0)) {
        window.location = newLink;
    } else if(button && button === 1) {
        window.open(newLink, '_blank');
    }
});
```

This code will determine if it was a left click or middle click, and either redirect current page, or open in a new window/tab accordingly.

Code works fine in Chrome/IE as far as I can see. However, in the latest version of Firefox, only left click is working.

For a middle click, the event is not registered. So, my first thought was to look into what other event must be getting triggered. The only one I could find was either a mousedown/mouseup (click is a combination of these).

Using mousedown or mouseup, I then get the event to properly register a middle click in Firefox. HOWEVER, the problem then becomes that Firefox will refuse to open any new windows from javascript code that is not the result of a CLICK event.

So.... any clue if this is actually possible? I'd rather not make the user have to allow popups, or re-map their middle click function to open in the current window.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Firefox will not fire the click event for a middle click on an anchor element "to don't break the web", as "a lot of sites assume that "onclick" is only fired for the left button (since that is what IE and NS4 do)." See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=156137 - It is a rather poor justification IMO as other newer browsers do fire it and not firing it takes out a lot of potential from us developers. Also Opera didn't fire the click event for middle clicks last time I checked as well. Are you sure mouseup doesn't work? It should still count as user interaction.

Comment: if(button && button == 0)) { <-- this line has a ')' too many...

Answer (score 1):

> However, in some browsers the default actions of the right and middle mouse buttons cannot be disabled, or can only be disabled by changing browser settings. Such changes to browser settings typically effect all pages viewed through the browser, and typically cannot be done from Javascript. Since few users will want to do this, it pretty much means that the those mouse events are not usable from Javascript.

from http://www.unixpapa.com/js/mouse.html